# How to calculate "Redemption value of Preferred Stocks" in Compustat (Global) database [WRDS Database]

Tags: stock, wrds-compusat

"Redemption Value of Preferred Stocks " (Compustat#56) for Compustat (North America) database is available, which is sum of "redeemable Preferred Stocks" and "Preferred dividends in arrears". In Compustat (Global) database "Redemption Value of preferred Stock" as well as "Preferred dividends in arrears" are unavailable.

Can someone please suggest, which proxy variable can be closest to calculate "Redemption Value of Preferred Stocks" using variables available in Compustat (Global)